# Graph API me/home posts disappear and appear

Tags: facebook, web-applications, facebook-graph-api

I am using graph API 'me/home' to get the posts in news feed. Since last week posts disappear and then reappear in response received. The first call gives the response with post x. In the second request post x is missing. In the third request the response contains post x and this response is identical to response of first call. This behavior repeats after several correct responses in subsequent requests.

Also this behavior repeats for the same set of posts.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will add code. How ever this not an issue with implementation. Had checked by manually calling facebook graph api using https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token=... url. For example  for testing made 20 calls. The first 12 calls gave the same data. one post was missing in 13th call and all other calls after that had the same data as the first 12 calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you describe above, it sounds like one of the servers in Facebook's cluster may have a stale cache it's sending back to you. If you continue seeing it, you can log it as a bug with facebook.

Comment: Thanks. The issue is still happening. Implemented a workaround using cache. The list of posts were stored in cache and a post is removed from cache only if this post is missing continuously in multiple responses.

Comment: Then please log it as a bug and report back here with the bug number.  Thanks.